# How to plot differences in temperatures on a map (geom_map)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I had to produce a worldwide map of the level of temperature in March 2010, which I managed to do with the following code:

```
temperature_data %>% filter(date >= as.Date("2010-03-01") & date <= as.Date("2010-03-31"))%>%
  ggplot(aes(map_id=country))+
  geom_map(mapping=aes(fill=temperature), map=map_data("world")) +
  expand_limits(x=world$long, y=world$lat) +
  ggtitle("Worlwide map of temperatures in March 2010") +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(size=15, face="bold", color="black"))+
  xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="blue", high="orange")
```

However, I now need to plot the same thing but with the differences in temperatures between March 2010 and March 1900. 
How can I make differences with dates in such a case?

Thanks in advance,

Regards

Comment: This seems like a data manipulation question, not a plotting question. Get one data set with the March 2010 temps, get another with the March 1900 temps, join them on location, take the difference between the two temp columns. Your same plotting code should work just fine, but it's difficult to help without sample data. What complicating factors are there? Do you have the same countries in 2010 as in 1900? How do you want to handle changes in countries? Is your data complete for 1900? How to handle missing data?...

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
In fact I managed to find the solution. I did not see the problem like I should have. It was quite a simple problem after all :)